# Idiom, common phrase crossword puzzle challenge 3

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. 語出《易經． 繫辭下》It means that when things develop to the extreme and exhaustion, they must seek changes. After the changes, they will be accessible and suitable for needs.
2. Strict teachers have great students
3. Can't help but do
4. At the end of one's rope
5. Unreasonable
6. Be hoisted with one's own petard
7. Indiscriminately kill innocent people
8. 岳飛的罪名 (Yue Fei's Charge)
9. inquire after someone's well-being
10. Ambiguous
11. extremely wealthy
12. Not for Children (For adult only)
13. Free and contented
14. Extravagantly grand 出自宋·罗大经《鹤林玉露》补遗
15. 五嶽之首 (Head of the Five Sacred Mountains)
16. very old age
17. Bankrupt
18. Suffering
19. Water from far away cannot put out a fire nearby
20. Nepotism
21. Completely disintegrate
22. Find common ground and keep different opinions。出自《礼记·乐记》

A. Birds and animals

B. It is a metaphor for the outflow of talents from one country to work in other countries. 出自《左传·襄公二十六年》。

C. When you are poor on a street, no one cares about you; when you are rich, distant relatives will seek you out in the mountains

D. Read very fast

E. Refugee

F. Barbarians

G. Prescription

H. Pretentious

I. The five elements

J. Understanding, reasonable

K. To emerge and perish on its own

L. Lovely person (refers to a young female)

M. Strictly forbidden

N. Feel shame for receiving an undeserved reward

O. 形容家庭和顺，夫妻和睦 出自《诗经·周南·桃夭》Means to describe the family harmony; harmony between husband and wife

P. Shoplifting

Q. Wipeout, no longer exist

R. Famous mountains and great rivers

- *If you cannot solve the blank puzzle, please try the one below with additional word hints*

> [image: Hinted Puzzle]

Comment: I don't think posting a word puzzle here is a good idea...

Comment: @AurusHuang we already had a discussion about this. While I am personally neutral, others believe this kind of "question" is on-topic, because it's about learning Chinese. You can voice your opinions in [this meta thread](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1847)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third time! I really don't want to see it happening again. Why don't you join it, friends?

> [image: My Answer... Again.]

Comment: Perfect, You got it the first time. I don't think the blank one can be solved in such a short time. The goal of games is to challenge the players, not frustrate them, so the additional word hints are better suited for the general public. Leave the blanked one to the hard-core gamers